# Pandas - Empty Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load the following data into my `pandas` `dataframe`:

```
jsons_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['playlist', 'user', 'track', 'count'])

for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
  with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
    json_text = json.load(json_file)
    #my json layout
    user = json_text.keys()
    playlist = 'all_playlists'
    track = [p for p in json_text.values()[0]]
    count = [p.values() for p in json_text.values()]
    print jsons_data
```

but I get an `empty dataframe`:

```
[u'user1']
all_playlists
[{u'Make You Feel My Love': 1.0, u'I See Fire': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'One': 1.0, u'Goodbye My Lover': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
[u'user2']
all_playlists
[{u'Codex': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Go It Alone': 1.0}]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
[u'user3']
all_playlists
[{u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
[u'user4']
all_playlists
[{u'No Distance Left To Run': 1.0, u'Running Up That Hill': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
[u'user5']
all_playlists
[{u'Wild Wood': 1.0, u'You Do Something To Me': 1.0, u'Reprise': 1.0}]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [playlist, user, track, count]
Index: []
```

what is wrong with the code?

EDIT:

`json` files are structured in this fashion:

```
{
'user1':{
'Karma Police':1.0,
'Roxanne':1.0,
'Sonnet':1.0,
'We Will Rock You':1.0,
}}
```

Comment: You initialized your DataFrame with no values and some column names: `['playlist', 'user', 'track', 'count']`... what else did you expect? You never once touch the `DataFrame` in your loop - how could it possibly affect it?

Comment: I don't know. I'm learning. maybe you could teach me.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service. I suggest you read the `pandas` [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html), though. It should have you up and running in no time.

Comment: indeed, not a tutorial service. but the vast majority here serve politeness instead of sarcasm. thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of your JSON files you use?

Comment: @JulienMarrec of course. please refer to edit.

Comment: A bit more please, or least tell me if there's more than one user per file or something?

Comment: each and every `json_file` in `path` has the same structure, with one user only. `json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]`. does that help?

Comment: if I add `jsons_data.loc[index] = [playlist, user, track, count]`at the end of loop, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first let's start by making some dummy data to play with that will make the comprehension of this problem much easier:

```
# Dummy data to play with
data1 = {
'user1':{
    'Karma Police':1.0,
    'Roxanne':1.0,
    'Sonnet':1.0,
    'We Will Rock You':1.0,
    }
}

data2 = {
'user2':{
    'Karma Police':1.0,
    'Creep':1.0,
    }
}
```

Let me illustrate something we'll use below:

```
In : pd.DataFrame(data1).unstack()

Out:
user1  Karma Police        1.0
       Roxanne             1.0
       Sonnet              1.0
       We Will Rock You    1.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
# This is where you would normally iterate on the files
mylist = []
for data in [data1, data2]:
    # Make a dataframe then unstack,
    # producing a series with a 2-multiindex as above
    # And append it to the lsit
    mylist.append(pd.DataFrame(data).unstack())
```

Now we concat that list, and do a little bit of cleaning up

```
merged = pd.concat(mylist)
# Renaming to get the right column names
merged.index.names = ['User', 'Track']
merged.name = 'Count'
# Transpose to a dataframe instead of a Series
merged = merged.to_frame()
# Adding a new column with the same value throughout
merged['Playlist'] = 'all_playlists'


merged
```

Out:

[image: Output]

You could then call reset_index if you don't like it this way.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the loop, simply add:

```
jsons_data.loc[index] = [playlist, user, track, count]
```

it prints:

```
  playlist                  user  \
0    decaf           [user1]   
1    decaf           [user2]   
2    decaf           [user3]   
3    decaf           [user4]   
4    decaf           [user5]   

                                               track  \
0  [Make You Feel My Love, I See Fire, High And D...   
1              [Codex, No Surprises, O, Go It Alone]   
2   [Fake Plastic Trees, High And Dry, No Surprises]   
3  [No Distance Left To Run, Running Up That Hill...   
4       [Wild Wood, You Do Something To Me, Reprise]   

                                   count  
0  [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  
1                 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  
2                      [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  
3            [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  
4                      [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: That's pretty hard to work with no? Completely beats the point of using pandas

Comment: @JulienMarrec data analysis is not the friendliest environment. but it seems that, once the heavy weight is lifted by this framework, plotting the data and exporting the data(`SQLite` etc) it quite straightforward.